# Python Selenium Upload File without an Input Element

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, file-upload

I'm using Selenium in Python trying to upload a file but the html element isn't an input element. It's an "a" element with an onclick that calls javascript to popup a browser window.

I've tried to use send_keys to the "a" button but I get an error. I tried going deeper into the "a" element but all there is an "i" element that is an icon and a "span" element that says "Upload".

I've also tried using win32com.client to click() on the "a" element which opens up the file explorer and to navigate to the file I want to upload and then send a "{ENTER}" command to confirm the file selection but it didn't work.

Is there's a way to inject the file I want to upload into the onClick javascript that's with the "a" element I could try that but I'd rather just have a way of doing a send_keys(filePATH) to an element since I don't know how to interact or find the javascript file on the webpage.

```
# I'm leaving out the code that is unnecessary 
import os
import time
import win32com.client
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

chromedriver = "C:\\Users\\srichar133\\Downloads\\Daily Grind Auto Tool\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)


# normal webdriver way
uploadButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CRTaskDetailsAttachmentsInnerContainer"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a')
uploadButton.send_keys("C://Users/srichar133/Downloads/Daily Grind Auto Tool/Standard CR MOP 5.0.docx")
time.sleep(2)

# win32com way
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CRTaskDetailsAttachmentsInnerContainer"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a').click()
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
# I've already tried both ways of using backslashes in prior tests, the problem is elsewhere 
shell.Sendkeys("C:\\Users\\srichar133\\Downloads\\Daily Grind Auto Tool\\Standard CR MOP 5.0.docx")
time.sleep(3)
shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(3)

'''
html code
<a class="btn btn-info svgfont" style="border-radius:24px; padding: 2px 30px;" onclick="Model.CRTaskDetails.BrowseFile()">
'''
```

When I do the send_keys command: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

When I do the win32com way the script ignores the Sendkeys command to find the file destination and then the selenium script goes to the next click on the list after a long wait and creates an error saying it can't click on the item because the computer is still on the file explorer without a file destination found.

*** Additional Edit 7/22/2019 8:34AM ***

I found the javascript that gets activated when the user clicks on the button. Is there a way for me to send the attachment through the javascript to the website?

```
    self.LoadAttachment = function () {

        var attachData = null;
        if (Model.TaskDetails != undefined && Model.TaskDetails.taskDetails() != undefined && Model.TaskDetails.taskDetails()['MT_AttachmentData'] != undefined) {
            attachData = Model.TaskDetails.taskDetails()['MT_AttachmentData'];
        }

        if (attachData == undefined) {
            if (self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin != undefined) {
                var attachmentPluginObject = {
                    Model: self.Model,
                    ParentModel: 'Task',
                    TicketId: self.Wo_Id
                };
                self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin.pluginData = attachmentPluginObject;
                self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin.Load();
            }
        } else {
            if (self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin != undefined) {
                var attachmentPluginObject = {
                    Model: self.Model,
                    ParentModel: 'Task',
                    TicketId: self.Wo_Id
                };
                self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin.pluginData = attachmentPluginObject;
                self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin.SetAttachmentsPluginData(attachData);
            }
        }
    };

    self.OpenAttachments = function () {
        $('#' + self.Model + 'AttachmentsContainer').toggle('slow');
    };

    self.BrowseFile = function () {
        if (Object.keys(self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin.pluginData).length === 0) {
            self.LoadAttachment();
        }
        self.worklogsAttachmentPlugin.OpenFileBrowser();
        $('#' + self.Model + 'AttachmentsContainer').show('slow');
    };

    self.DownloadAttachment = function (attachmentName, type, attachmentId) {
        if (type == 3) {
            Helper.Utility.DownloadAttachment(attachmentName, self.Model);
        }
        else {
            Helper.Utility.DownloadDBDocument(attachmentName, self.Model, attachmentId);
        }
    };
```

Comment: If I do go the route of using ".click()" on the element how will I automate the file being selected and sent to the website without using an outside software like AutoIt. I'd just like to use python selenium or another python library to do it.

Comment: check if there is a hidden `input` with `type=file`? If you have one, then just send the upload file path to that hidden file input.

Comment: There isn't a hidden type in the input because there isn't an input element. I found the javascript that it runs. What can I do to upload through the javascript instead?