# Uploading files with Python Selenium without an 'input' html

Tags: python, html, selenium, file-upload

I want to upload a file for Python Selenium however, the send_keys method (sending the keys with the directory of your file) does not work, I get a 'Message: element not interactable'. This is due to the fact that my upload button does not contain an 'input' on its html code. The code I currently have allows you to click on the 'upload files' button which then opens the little Mac Os window. After that, I have no idea what I can do. It is quite obvious that the send_keys method does not work.

The website I'm using also allows drag and drop, however I have been told that the drag and drop for Selenium does not work.

I was reading a lot about it but I couldn't find a solution specific to Python. A lot of the solutions referred to Java but I couldn't find any for Python. Anything I could do?

## Here is the code I have:

button8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'FileName') and contains(@class,'x-btn')]")
button8.click()
time.sleep(1)
button9 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'ext-comp-1056') and contains(@class,'x-btn')]")
button9.click()
button9.send_keys('/Users/sebastiendupont/Desktop/Screen Shot 2019-08-26 at 4.12.03 PM')

## Here is the HTML code of the 'upload' button, I replaced the < with ( and > with ), because otherwise StackOverflow wouldn't display the html code

(table id="ext-comp-1056" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn btn-right upload-files x-btn-noicon" style="width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 1;")(tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left")(tr)(td class="x-btn-tl")(i) (/i)(/td)(td class="x-btn-tc")(/td)(td class="x-btn-tr")(i) (/i)(/td)(/tr)(tr)(td class="x-btn-ml")(i) (/i)(/td)(td class="x-btn-mc")(em class=" x-unselectable" unselectable="on")(button type="button" id="ext-gen179" class=" x-btn-text")+ Upload files...(/button)(/em)(/td)(td class="x-btn-mr")(i) (/i)(/td)(/tr)(tr)(td class="x-btn-bl")(i) (/i)(/td)(td class="x-btn-bc")(/td)(td class="x-btn-br")(i) (/i)(/td)(/tr)(/tbody)(/table)(

The codes sends the following classic message:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Please advise that I am very beginner at Python and Selenium but I have used complex codes. 
Thank you!

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122199/python-selenium-upload-file-without-an-input-element

Comment: Hey, I don't believe this link is solved. The problem still remains.

Comment: format your code.. it's unreadable

Answer (score 0):

You can use external tool AutoIT. You have to write script in AutoIT editor first and then compile it so it will generate .exe file.

After that you have to execute that .exe file in python using below code

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(<path to AutoIT .exe file>)
```